# Indefinite integral of an infinite sum.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate: $$\int \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^ndx$$ Here's how I proceded: $$\int(1 + 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3 + \dots )dx$$ $$= x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + \dots + C = \frac{x}{1-x} + C$$

But the book says that the answer is: $$\frac{1}{1-x} + C$$ How?! Also, can we write the series inside the integral in a closed form, and proceed to solve further from there?

Comment: $\frac{x}{1-x}=\frac{1}{1-x}-1$, so your $C$ and the book's $C$ are different. More precisely, $C_{\text{yours}}-1=C_{\text{book}}$ (which is fine, since antiderivatives are only determined up to a constant)

Comment: @peek-a-boo Oh I see, but that doesn't make my answer wrong, right?

Comment: Your answer is also correct

Comment: Thanks, that was useful info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, $$\frac{x}{1-x}=\frac1{1-x}-1,$$
so
$$\begin{align}
\frac{x}{1-x}+(\text{constant})&=\frac{1}{1-x}-1+(\text{constant})\\
&=\frac{1}{1-x}+(\text{constant}),
\end{align}$$
and thus your antiderivative is still correct.

---

EDIT:

A request was made for the closed form of the sum inside the integral. This is simple to do. Start with the sum
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n\ge0}x^n.$$
Then differentiate both sides:
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n\ge0}nx^{n-1}=0+\sum_{n\ge1}nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n\ge0}(n+1)x^n$$

Comment: Wow, that's interesting! Is there something deeper happening here then you can explain??? Interesting how we can get rid of the $x$ in the numerator and still have  the correct antiderivativetive... Is there a more general situation where something similar to this happens?

Comment: The general situation: two rational functions differ by a constant iff their difference has numerator equal to a constant times the denominator.

Comment: @Frogwilldo we have $$1=\frac{1-x}{1-x}=\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{x}{1-x}$$

Comment: I see that. Still weird that we can get rid of that $x$ like that and still have the correct antiderivative!

Comment: And do you any views on the the second part of the questionm

Comment: @NickLarry see the edit